# How to find a CLSID in rust for windows?

Tags: winapi, rust, com, clsid, windows-rs

I'm using rust for windows to use the win32 API.
However, I need to initialize com library to use some windows APIs, but I cannot find some classes ID (CLSID), to create an instance.
I need to find the Speech ISpVoice CLSID to use in my instance creation.
`CLSID_SpVoice` is the CLSID.
Also, I cannot find some macros like "FAILED", and "SUCCEEDED".
If anyone can direct me, that would be appreciated!
Also, if there's any error in my code, please highlight it me.
Code:

```
    use windows::Win32::System::Com::{CoInitializeEx, CoCreateInstance};
use windows::Win32::System::{Com, Ole};
use windows::core::{ HRESULT, Error };
use windows::Win32::Media::Speech::ISpVoice;

fn main() {
    let speaker: ISpVoice;
    unsafe {
        if CoInitializeEx(std::ptr::null(), Com::COINIT_MULTITHREADED) ==Result::Ok(()) {
            let hr: HRESULT = CoCreateInstance(, punkouter, dwclscontext)
        }
    }
}
```

**If anything is unclear, please let me know!**

Comment: https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=CLSID_SpVoice => 96749377-3391-11d2-9ee3-00c04f797396. This site also tells you the value is available in the Windows SDK headers at %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\sapi53.h (adapt to your setup and SDK version). SUCCEEDED is defined here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winerror/nf-winerror-succeeded and FAILED here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winerror/nf-winerror-failed

Comment: @Simon Mourier, I haven't ask for C++ headers, I asked for the Windows crate (Rust For Windows).  The two are different.

Comment: I just assumed that `#define SUCCEEDED(hr) (((HRESULT)(hr)) >= 0)` was easy to understand for any programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`windows`](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate declares the [`SpVoice`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Media/Speech/constant.SpVoice.html) constant which is the value of the `CLSID_SpVoice` class ID. As you have discovered, that's the `CLSID` you want to pass into [`CoCreateInstance`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/System/Com/fn.CoCreateInstance.html).

The latter returns a [`windows::core::Result<T>`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/core/type.Result.html), which models the same semantics as C code using the [`SUCCEEDED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winerror/nf-winerror-succeeded) and [`FAILED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winerror/nf-winerror-failed) macros would. You can either `match` on the `Ok` or `Err` variants manually, or use the `?` operator for convenient error propagation:

```rust
use std::ptr;

use windows::{
    core::Result,
    Win32::{
        Media::Speech::{ISpVoice, SpVoice},
        System::Com::{CoCreateInstance, CoInitializeEx, CLSCTX_ALL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED},
    },
};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    unsafe { CoInitializeEx(ptr::null(), COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED) }?;
    let _speaker: ISpVoice = unsafe { CoCreateInstance(&SpVoice, None, CLSCTX_ALL) }?;

    Ok(())
}
```

In case you need a `CLSID` that's not available through the `windows` crate, you can always construct a [`GUID`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/core/struct.GUID.html) constant using either [`from_values`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/core/struct.GUID.html#method.from_values) or [`from_u128`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/core/struct.GUID.html#method.from_u128):

```rust
const CLSID_SpVoice: GUID = GUID::from_u128(0x96749377_3391_11d2_9ee3_00c04f797396);
```

Note that the value is *exactly* the value you were given in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73098224/how-to-find-a-clsid-in-rust-for-windows/73101804#comment129102433_73098224). Your assessment that C++ and Rust were any different with respect to COM is unfounded. They are indeed the same thing, just with different syntax.

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution.
I'll let my answer for anyone may encounter this problem:
Instead of providing the Class ID of the ISpVoice, I referenced the SpVoice struct to the CoCreateInstance method then it returns the SpVoice struct.
As following:

```
let speaker: ISpVoice = CoCreateInstance(&SpVoice, None, CLSCTX_ALL)?;
```

This method will work with any CoCreateInstance.
However, I'm still stuck with the two macros: "FAILED", and "SUCCEEDED".
If anyone know, please let me know also.